# Две страницы на одном листе при генерации pdf puppeteer-ом

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, puppeteer

Есть html-документ из которого puppeteer-ом [генерируется pdf](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagepdfoptions).

Как мне привести сгенерированный pdf к виду "две страницы на лист"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это невозможно сделать pagepdfoptions то как это сделать html+css?

Comment: @muturgan, ты знаешь как?

Comment: а это разве не в момент печати только выбирать? Либо в самом просмотрщике пдф?

Comment: а если установить значения ширины и высоты в опциях в два раза меньше стандартного А4? CSS можно накидать, но это фактически вторая верстка

Comment: @Yugofx у меня контент документа формируется динамически, так что нет проблемы добавить в шаблон что-то css-ное. вечером подключу https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css и попробую твоё предложение