# Что означает оператор ?? в javascript

Tags: javascript

В документации  next.js наткнулся на код вида:

```js
store ?? initStore(preloadedState)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) - в случае если переданное значение `null` или `undefined` вернет значение после `??`

```js
console.log(null ?? 'null/undefined val');
console.log(undefined ?? 'null/undefined val');
console.log(0 ?? 'null/undefined val');
```

Comment: возможно, лучше бы вместо "переданное значение" написать "левое значение"

Comment: Что интересно, оно не маскирует ReferenceError. Например, в php выражение  `$asdasd ?? 2;` вычисляется в 2. =)

Comment: @nörbörnën, ну для меня это функция которая возвращает переданный параметр либо значение по умолчанию. "Оператор нуллевого слияния" - как-то странно звучит, нужно как-то по другому перевести

Comment: @Grundy мне и англ не нравится как звучит. в perl эта штука называется "Logical Defined-Or" - просто и понятно. но, всё же, любой русский перевод улучшает ответ. (п.с. загляни в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197607/2659 если знаешь puppeteer)

Answer (score 4):

Это оператор объединения с null:

https://learn.javascript.ru/nullish-coalescing-operator

Результат выражения `a ?? b` будет следующим:

1. `a`, если значение `a` определено,
2. `b`, если значение `a` не определено.

и равносильно следующему коду:

```
result = (a !== null && a !== undefined) ? a : b;
```

поскольку в javascript таких ситуаций было много, то добавили такую возможность

Comment: на самом деле проверка проще: `a != null` :)